# How to name variables in a data array using a for loop

Tags: arrays, matlab, variables, for-loop

I have an array within an array and I am trying to name the variables using a for loop as there are a lot of variables. When I use the following simple code `Time1  = dataCOMB{1,1}{1,1}(1:1024, 1);` it opens the first cell in an array and proceeds to open the first cell in the following array and finally defines all the values in column 1 rows 1 to 1024 as `Time1`. However I have 38 of these different sets of data and when I apply the following code:

```
for t = 1:38
    for aa = 1:38
        Time(t)  = dataCOMB{1,1}{1,aa}(1:1024, 1);
    end
end
```

I get an error

> In an assignment  A(I) = B, the number of elements in B and I must be the same.
>
> Error in Load_Files_working (line 39)
>      Time(t)  = dataCOMB{1,1}{1,aa}(1:1024, 1);

Basically I am trying to get matlab to call the first column in each data set `Time1`, `Time2`, etc.

Comment: What you are trying to do there is copying the contents of `dataCOMB` into `Time(t)`, which is not the same as renaming, because changing `Time(t)` won't change `dataCOMB`. Are you just reading from `dataCOMB` or will you be writing in there?

Answer (score 1):

**The problem:**

1)You'd want to extract in a cell row...

2) ...the first 1024 numbers in the 1st column...

3) ...from each of the first 38 cells of a cell array.

**The plan:**

1) If one wants to get info from each element of a cell array (that is, an array accessed via `{}` indexing), one may use [`cellfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html). Calling `cellfun(some_function, a_cell_array)` will aggregate the results of `some_function(a_cell_array{k})` for all possible `k` subscripts. If the results are heterogeneous (i.e. not having the same type and size), one may use the `cell_fun(..., 'UniformOutput', false`) option to put them in an output cell array (cell arrays are good at grouping together heterogeneous data).

2) To extract the first 1024 numbers from the first column of an numeric array `x` one may use this *anonymous* function: `@(x) x(1:1024,1)`. The `x` argument will com from each element of a cell array, and our anonymous function will play the role of `some_function` in the step above.

3) Now we need to specify `a_cell_array`, i.e. the cell array that contains the first 38 cells of the target. That would be, simply `dataCOMB{1,1}(1,1:38)`.

**The solution:**

This one-liner implements the plan:

```
Time = cellfun(@(x) x(1:1024,1), dataCOMB{1,1}(1,1:38), 'UniformOutput', false);
```

Then you can access your data as in this example:

```
this_time = Time{3};
```

Comment: Very impressive. IMO, it might difficult for a newish person to parse.  It's a tour-de-force of tight programming, though.  Wow.

Comment: @chipaudette Oh, you flatter me. :-) IMHO, one-liners are a bit stream-of-consciousness kind of programming, so they're not easily-readable. I'll modify my answer so it will be more expressive and -- thus -- less impressive. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your error is with `Time(t)`.  That's not how you create a new variable in matlab.  To do exactly what you want (ie, create variables names `Time1`, `Time2`, etc...you'll need to use the `eval` function:

```
for aa = 1:38
    eval(['Time' num2str(aa) '= dataCOMB{1,1}{1,aa}(1:1024,1);']);
end
```

Many people do not like recommending the `eval` function.  Others wouldn't recommend moving all of your data out of a data structure and into their own independently-named variables.  So, to address these two criticisms, a better alternative might be to pull your data out of your complicated data structure and to put it into a simpler array:

```
Time_Array = zeros(1024,38);
for aa = 1:38
    Time_Array(:,aa) = dataCOMB{1,1}{1,aa}(1:1024,1);
end
```

Or, if you don't like that because you really like the names `Time1`, `Time2`, etc, you could create them as fields to a data structure:

```
Time_Data = [];
for aa = 1:38
    fieldname = ['Time' num2str(aa)];
    Time_Data.(fieldname) = dataCOMB{1,1}{1,aa}(1:1024,1);
end
```

And, in response to a comment below by the original post, this method can be extended to further unpack the data:

```
Time_Data = [];
count = 0;
for z = 1:2;
    for aa = 1:38
       count = count+1;
       fieldname = ['Time' num2str(count)];
       Time_Data.(fieldname) = dataCOMB{1,z}{1,aa}(1:1024,1);
    end
end
```

Comment: Umm, let's better ignore the `eval`-approach altogether.

Comment: Can you add some text to help the OP understand why the `eval` approach should be avoided?

Comment: Thanks for the help, it worked :) I have one further question.Is there a way that when the first 38 variables are named then I can update the following line `Time_Data.(fieldname) = dataCOMB{1,z}{1,aa}(1:1024,1);`Where z will now update to the number 2 instead of 1 as before. This will then allow me to name the second batch of variables Time39 to Time 76 and so on?

Comment: I'd say additionally to [Loren's blog post](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2005/12/28/evading-eval/), especially in this case: When you will be doing anything with these variable later on, you will only be able to do so using `eval`. I'm not perfectly sure on how to talk best about topics that are possible, but bad practice. I just thought the simplest approach would be to sweep it under the carpet.

Comment: I decided to make a data structure as chipaudette suggested. I keep reading a lot about best practices and to avoid using eval so I try to avoid it where possible

Comment: I extended my response above to address the case that you requested.  If this works as you like, don't forget to mark this post as "answered".